# indexPath.row throws an exception

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, custom-cell

I'm toggling the datasource of an tableview but the indexPath.row throws me an exception [index x beyond bounds]

```
cell.customLabel.text = [[(_secondTab.selected) ? secondArray : firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]elementName];
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Make sure there are enough elements in your two arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the index `indexPath.row` is larger than what exists in either `secondArray` or `firstArray`.  To fix the root cause, you need to figure out why the element is missing from your arrays.  To ensure it doesn't crash and simply loads an empty string in the label's text property, check that the largest index in the array is greater than or equal to `indexPath.row`:

```
if (_secondTab.selected) { 
    cell.customLabel.text = (indexPath.row <= ([secondArray count]-1)) ? [[secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] elementName] : @"";
} else {
    cell.customLabel.text = (indexPath.row <= ([firstArray count]-1)) ? [[firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] elementName] : @"";
}
```

Comment: I don't want to display the empty elements from my second array. How I do that?

Comment: Change `@"";` in the if-statement to a string that contains the text you want to display instead in the event that `indexPath.row` is beyond the bounds of `secondArray`.  If you don't want to display the tableView rows at all, you will need to remove the objects from the `secondArray` dataSource before `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.  Where depends on how the app is structured, a good place would be the location you populate `secondArray`

Comment: `elementName` is the object which returns the text; How it would look without @"" ?

Answer (score 1):

This may occur when the index value is out of range. Make sure that secondArray and firstArray has same number of values. Or else use your logic to verify that it is out of range or not?

For example, if the datasource is secondArray, your `indexPath.row` is 4

firstArray has 3 values, secondArray has 6 values. In that situation `[firstArray objectAtIndex:4]` will throw an exception.